# Set a new enivironment variable using a file content

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a certain file.txt with the next content

```
#pfc.diskusage 0.90 0.95
```

How can I set two new environment variables giving the numbers 0.90 and 0.95 within the file as an input expecting to set two new environment variables like this?

```
{...,'NEW_ENV_VAR1': '0.90',
 'NEW_ENV_VAR1': '0.95'}
```

I tried it out by using 'sed' command specifying the line, but I could not manage to make it work this way.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are after setting env variables for another program - or after a transformation from that input file to some json-ish output

Comment: No, I am not. I just need to set the env variables.

Comment: `to set two new environment variables like this? {...,'NEW_ENV_VAR1': '0.90',
 'NEW_ENV_VAR1': '0.95'}` like a json? Environment variable is environment variable, not a json, how is this `{...` related to it? Are you trying to set environment variable or create a json?

Comment: It was just a display example, not the actual env variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could probably try to use arrays to get access to those columns:

```
X=( `echo '#pfc.diskusage 0.90 0.95'` )
export NEW_ENV_VAR1=${X[1]}
export NEW_ENV_VAR2=${X[2]}
```

Comment: Please do not use \` backticks - use `$(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
readarray -d ' ' -n 3 -s 1 <file.txt
export NEW_ENV_VAR1=${MAPFILE[0]}
export NEW_ENV_VAR2=${MAPFILE[2]}
```

Explanation:

`readarray` reads the content of standard input into an array named `MAPFILE`. Usually one line would take up one array element. The `-d ' '` option says that we want to use a space as record delimiter, and the `-s 1` says that we want to skip the first record (which is *#pfc.diskusage*)